# How can I check if my code is SQL injection proof?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-injection

I am already using `mysqli_real_escape_string` for every user input. I did try to enter the following value inside a `textarea` which was later meant to be stored in the database.

```
Something'); DROP TABLE table_name;--
```

It did not delete `table_name` from the database and the value was stored exactly like `Something'); DROP TABLE table_name;--` in one of the tables. No character was escaped. This made me doubt if `mysqli_real_escape_string` is actually working or not.

Is user input saved without escaping any characters even when we run the input through `mysqli_real_escape_string`?

If the input is indeed saved with with escaped characters, why was the query saved without any changes in my case? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just use prepared statements and be home in time for corn flakes.  The SQL injection problem was solved a long time ago, and you should not be spending your development energy on this problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am working on an old project originally created by someone else. In this particular instance, updating the whole code to use prepared statements would be very time consuming imho. :)

Comment: Yes, there would be some initial overhead, but it is worth the investment IMO, and later down the road you would probably save time.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you are probably right, updating the code now will save me time in future. :)